# How to impute a three-level dataset with ordered and continuous variables with non-normal distribution in R using `mi` in R

Tags: r, imputation, multilevel-analysis, mi

I am currently trying to impute missing entries in a three-level dataset using the `mi`-package.

Currently, I am facing two issues with how to impute multilevel data correctly:

- Firstly, the variables at level two and three are imputed with different values within the same cluster/ID.
- Secondly, I am also unable to set the boundaries for a continuous variable that cannot have values outside a specific interval.

###### Problem 1. How to create a `multilevel_missing_data.frame`

[The documentation](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/mi/mi.pdf) states that:

> ###### Objects from the Class
>
> Objects can be created by calls of the form `new("multilevel_missing_data.frame", ...)`.
> However, its users almost always will pass a `data.frame` to the `missing_data.frame` function
> and specify the `subclass` and `groups` arguments.
>
> ###### Slots
>
> The `multilevel_missing_data.frame` class inherits from the `missing_data.frame`-class and has
> two additional slots
>
> - **groups** Object of class `character` indicating which variables define the multilevel structure
> - **mdf_list** Object of class `mdf_list` whose elements contain a `missing_data.frame` for each group.
>   This slot is filled automatically by the `initialize` method.

If I understand the documentation correctly, it should be possible to create a `multilevel_missing_data.frame` by specifying `subclass` and `groups`:

```
library(dlpyr)
library(magrittr)
library(mi)

# loading and preparing data
url <- "https://simongrund1.github.io/posts/multiple-imputation-for-three-level-and-cross-classified-data_files/example_3l.Rdata"
download.file(url, basename(url))
load("example_3l.Rdata")
dat %<>%
mutate(
    z = as.ordered(round(z)+2),
    x = abs(x)
)

# Create multilevel_missing_data.frame
mdf <- missing_data.frame(
   dat,
   subclass = "multilevel",
   groups = c("class", "school"
)
```

```
# Output:
> Error in getClass(Class, where = topenv(parent.frame())): “NA” is not a defined class
```

###### Problem 2. Defining the boundaries in the `bounded-continuous` class

According to the documentation

> Objects can be created that are of `bounded-continuous` class via the the `missing_variable` generic
> function by specifying `type = "bounded-continuous"` as well as `lower` and / or `upper`

This means that I should be able to define a variable as `bounded-continuous` the following way:

```
missing_variable(
   dat$x,
   type = "bounded-continuous",
   lower = 0, upper = 5
)
```

However, I can not figure out how to add the defined variable to the `missing_data.frame` object together with all the other variables.

###### "working" example

(i.e. *the code runs*, but it *doesn't impute the values correctly* as the grouping variables are not defined, and boundaries for `x` are not set.):

```
library(dlpyr)
library(magrittr)
library(mi)

# loading and preparing data
url <- "https://simongrund1.github.io/posts/multiple-imputation-for-three-level-and-cross-classified-data_files/example_3l.Rdata"
download.file(url, basename(url))
load("example_3l.Rdata")
dat %<>%
mutate(
    z = as.ordered(round(z)+2),
    x = abs(x)
)

mdf <- missing_data.frame(dat) # Here I should define grouping variables somehow
mdf <- change(
    mdf,
    y = c("class", "school", "x"),
    what = "type",
    to = c("group", "group", "bounded-continuous")
) # Boundaries for "x" should be added here

mi_mdf <- mi(mdf, n.iter = 30, n.chains = 4, max.minutes = 20)
mi_mdf <- complete(mi_mdf, m = 1)

mi_mdf %>% select(class:w)
```

###### Output (incorrect):

- Variable "z" has varying values imputed for the same level 2 ("class") ID
- Variable "w" has varying values imputed for the same level 3 ("school") ID

```
class school x          y            z     w
<dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>        <ord> <dbl>
2      1     0.32023493 -1.024494036     3  1.329629 
2      1     0.06949615  0.547773458     3  1.329629
2      1     1.98737694  0.287954055     1  1.329629
⋮      ⋮              ⋮           ⋮    ⋮         ⋮
250   50     2.54218522   1.63412995     1 -1.52528136 # 
250   50     2.11927441   0.60549683     1 -1.17877900
250   50     2.01830248   1.27016541     1 -1.74640219
```

How can I define `class` as level 2 and `school` as level 3 variables, and how can I set the boundaries of `x` to 0 (lower) and 10 (upper)?

###### Desired output:

- Variable "z" has the same imputed value for each level 2 ("class") ID
- Variable "w" has the same imputed values for each level 3 ("school") ID
- "x" seemingly do not have values outside the desired range. (My assumption is that when defining a variable as `bounded-continuous`, boundaries are automatically set based on the range of the real values.) However, the boundaries should nonetheless be defined as the interval which the values can exist within.

```
class school x          y            z     w
<dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>        <ord> <dbl>
2      1     0.32023493 -1.024494036     3  1.329629
2      1     0.06949615  0.547773458     3  1.329629
2      1     1.98737694  0.287954055     3  1.329629
⋮      ⋮              ⋮           ⋮    ⋮         ⋮
250   50     2.54218522   1.63412995     1 -1.52528136
250   50     2.11927441   0.60549683     1 -1.52528136
250   50     2.01830248   1.27016541     1 -1.52528136
```

Comment: In the docs, it says `Objects can be created by calls of the form new("multilevel_missing_data.frame", ...).` and then u call the `missing_data.frame`

Comment: I am uncertain how to use `new()` for this purpose. Following your quote the documentation also states "However, its users almost always will pass a `data.frame` to the `missing_data.frame` function
and specify the `subclass` and `groups` arguments." See my updated post for elaboration.